# how to count no of documents for employee in mongo db

Tags: mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have Mongo DB collection now I want to calculate the count of document by each employee id, this could have been done in this way in sql.

```
select count(*), empid
from my_table
group by empid
```

Any idea how to achieve this in Mongo DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.table_name.aggregate([
{"$group":{_id:"$empid",count:{$sum:1}}} ])
```

Comment: I have executed this query on my collection, but its giving single values.
db.Transactions_2020.aggregate([{"$group":{_id:"SAPOD",count:{$sum:1}}} ])
Output : 
_id     count
SAPOD 428207945

Comment: I am sorry.. I dint get you. What do you mean by single values? Can you paste the json structure of the output?

Comment: {
  "_id" : "SAPOD",
  "count" : 428207945
}

Comment: where as desired results is :

{
{
  "SAPOD": "10",
  "count" : 1000
},
{
  "SAPOD" : "20",
  "count" : 2000
}
}

Comment: The missing of the $ symbol in your query is rendering only one value as you mentioned. Please change your query to **db.Transactions_2020.aggregate([{"$group":{_id:"$SAPOD",count:{$sum:1}}} ])** . In your case, the result should be {{_id:"10","count":1000},{_id:"20","count":2000}}.

Comment: If you need your results to be the way you want,  **db.Transactions_2020.aggregate([{"$group":{_id:{SAPOD:"$SAPOD"},count:{$sum:1}}} ])**. The result wouldn't be entirely the same way, but close enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can sum ones, one for each document:

```js
db.my_table.aggregate([
  $group: { _id: "empid", qty: { $sum: 1 }
]);
```